# Two equally distant points in a tree

Tags: python, tree

I'm solving the example probation problem in Python and had only partial success so far (passed 30 test cases, wrong answer in the 31st). The test cases themselves are not disclosed.

**Description.**

A network of n nodes connected by n-1 links is given. Find two nodes so that the distance from the fatherst node to the nearest of those two would be minimal. If several answers are possible, any of them will be accepted.

The input is given as a list of pairs of numbers. Each number represents node, pair is the connection between two nodes. The result should be the list of two nodes.

*Example 1*
in = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
result = [3, 1]

*Example 2*
in = [[1, 2], [3, 2], [2, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6]]
result = [2, 4]

My solution.

The net will always be a tree, not a graph. For the above examples the corresponding trees will be:

*example 1*

```
1-2-3
```

*example 2*

```
1     5
 \   /
  2-4
 /   \
3     6
```

My solution is based on going from leaves to the middle step by step, eventually removing nodes from the leaves -- one level after another. Finally I'll end up with a one or two nodes in the middle.

*Example A.*

```
1-2-3   8-9-10-14     2-3   8-9-10     3   8-9  
     \ /                 \ /            \ /  
      7           >>>     7        >>>   7     >>> 7-8  
     / \                 / \            / \  
4-5-6   11-12-13      5-6   11-12      6   11
```

result: [7, 8]

*Example B.*

```
1-2-3   8-9-10       2-3   8-9       3   8
     \ /                \ /           \ /
      7          >>>     7       >>>   7    >>> 7
     / \                / \           / \
4-5-6   11-12-13     5-6   11-12     6   11
```

result: [7, ...]

*Example C.*

```
11                 13
  \               /
 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10 >> ... >> 3-4-5-6-7-8 >> ... >> 5-6
  /               \
12                 14
```

result: [3, 8]

If we have more than two nodes after each step but the last (*example B*), then the answer will be the single middle node and any other node.
As to other cases if we have n steps to the middle point(s), and have two ends after half of n steps to the center (*example C*), that two ends will be equidistant from the ends of the original tree and from its middle (two middles are possible if the segment length is even). That two ends will be the answer. If we still don't have two ends after half of n steps (*example A*), than we will continue to move toward the middle and once the number of ends will be narrowed to two, that two ends will be the answer.

Possibly there is a flaw in the above reasoning and someone already can notice it at this point.

Now to the implementation.
I represent tree as a dictionary. Keys are numbers representing nodes and values are sets of numbers representing neighbour nodes. Removing ends from a tree comes to removing keys having only a single neighbour and removing the corresponding number from  all of its parents.

Below are the original tree representation and its first modification from the *example A*.

```
{1: {2},
 2: {1, 3},
 3: {2, 7},
 4: {5},
 5: {4, 6},
 6: {5, 7},
 7: {3, 6, 8, 11},
 8: {7, 9},
 9: {8, 10},
 10: {9, 14},
 11: {7, 12},
 12: {11, 13},
 13: {12},
 14: {10}}

{2: {3},
 3: {2, 7},
 5: {6},
 6: {5, 7},
 7: {3, 6, 8, 11},
 8: {7, 9},
 9: {8, 10},
 10: {9},
 11: {7, 12},
 12: {11}}
```

The implementation itself.

```
def f(pairs):
    if len(pairs) == 1:
        return pairs[0]
    tree = {}
    for a, b in pairs:  
        if a not in tree:
            tree[a] = set()
        if b not in tree:
            tree[b] = set()
        tree[a].add(b)
        tree[b].add(a)
    ends = {e for e in tree if len(tree[e]) == 1}
    slices = [ends.copy()]
    while len(tree.keys()) > 2:
        nx_ends = set()
        for end in ends:
            pars = tree.pop(end, set())
            nx_ends.update(pars)
            for par in pars:
                tree[par].remove(end)
        nx_ends = {e for e in nx_ends if len(tree[e]) < 2}
        ends = nx_ends.copy()
        if ends:
            slices.append(ends)
    steps = len(slices) // 2
    for ends in slices[steps:]:
        ends = list(ends)
        if len(ends) == 2:
            return ends
        if len(ends) == 1:
            end = ends[0]
            for el in pairs[0]:
                if el != end:
                    return [end, el]
```

My solution seems rather effective yet, once again, gives wrong answer in (unfortunately closed) 31st test case.

**UPDATE**

I've solved the task. The solution is based on the above one with some additional steps.

After I -- according to the former algorithm -- find the two candidate points from the longer ends I do the additional check -- whether they are really equidistant. If the number of steps to cover all the nodes from the two candidate points is more than the number of steps to reach two candidate points from the longer ends the additional shift to the center is perfromed.

The value of the shift is half of difference of the steps since every step to the center not only increases the distanse to the longer ends by one, but also decreases the distance to another end(s).

```
def get_slices(slic, dic, from_ends=False):
    visited = slic.copy()
    slices = []
    while slic:
        slices.append(slic.copy())
        nx_slice = set()
        for end in slic:
            neibs = dic[end]
            for neib in neibs:
                if neib not in visited:
                    nx_slice.add(neib)
        if from_ends:
            nx_slice = {e for e in nx_slice if len(dic[e] - visited) < 2}
        slic = nx_slice
        visited.update(slic)
    return slices


def get_pair(node, pairs):
    for pair in pairs:
        if node in pair:
            return pair


def f(pairs):
    dic = {}
    if len(pairs) == 1:
        return pairs[0]
    for a, b in pairs:
        if a not in dic:
            dic[a] = set()
        if b not in dic:
            dic[b] = set()
        dic[a].add(b)
        dic[b].add(a)
    ends = {e for e in dic if len(dic[e]) == 1}
    slices = get_slices(ends, dic, from_ends=True)
    steps = len(slices) // 2
    slices = slices[steps:]
    while len(slices[0]) > 2:
        slices.pop(0)
        steps += 1
    slic = slices.pop(0)
    slices_center = get_slices(slic, dic)
    steps_center = len(slices_center) - 1
    slices_center.clear()
    diff = steps_center - steps
    if diff > 1:
        slic = slices[diff // 2 - 1]
    if len(slic) == 1:
        [r] = slic
        return get_pair(r, pairs)
    return slic
```

My question now is whether my solution is overcomplicated? Could you give a tip on a simpler one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the basic algorithmic error in my implementation and can demonstrate it with an example.

```
              52
               |
              53
               |
24-23-22-1-2-3-4-33-32-31-42-43-44
```

After eventually cutting ends according to my algorithm it'll be modified as follows.

```
           53
            |
23-22-1-2-3-4-33-32-31-42-43

22-1-2-3-4-33-32-31-42

1-2-3-4-33-32-31
```

The central nodes of segments 24-23-22-1-2-3-4 and 4-33-32-31-42-43-44 are 1 and 31 respectively and they will be considered as the answer. However, the node 52 turns out to be too distant from them.
The correct answer are nodes 2 and 32. If you see at the original tree you will easily notice that they are equidistant from nodes 24, 44 and 52, the distance equals 4.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve come to the solution that I’m more content with and, supposedly, is closer to the problem creator’s intention. The solution deals with such notions as *tree hight-balancing* and *reparenting*. Unfortunately it, as before, contains some subtle error that reveals as a runtime exception in one of the closed latter cases.

The algorithm is as follows.
First let’s suppose some arbitrary node is a root. Then we check each branch depth and find the longer branch. After that we accomplish reparenting: we change root to the branch higher node, the rest of the tree will then become the branch of the new tree.
In this way we continue reparenting until we come to to equally long branches or branches that differs in depth by one node. At this point we consider tree as a *hight-balanced*.
Than we consider (one of the) longer branches as a separate tree and the rest of the original tree as another separate tree and again balance those two trees by eventually reparenting. The roots of those balanced trees will be the answer.

Let’s illustrate with an example. Suppose we have the following tree.

```
                    52
                     |
                    53
                     |
  24-23-22-01-02-03-04-33-32-31-42-43-44
```

Suppose the root is 23 node. So we eventually reparent.

```
24
 |        23
23         |__
 |         |  |
22        22 24
 |         |
01        01
 |         |
02        02
 |         |
03        03
 |         |
04        04            04
 |__  >>   |__  >> … >>  |_____
 |  |      |  |          |  |  |
33 53     33 53         33 03 53
 |  |      |  |          |  |  |
32 52     32 52         32 02 52
 |         |             |  |
31        31            31 01
 |         |             |  |
42        42            42 22
 |         |             |  |
43        43            43 23
 |         |             |  |
44        44            44 24
```

Then we consider one of the longest branche (33-32-31-42-43-44) as one tree and the rest of the tree as another one tree.

```
04
 |__
 |  |
03 53    33
 |  |     |
02 52 …  32
 |        |
01       31
 |        |
22       42
 |        |
23       43
 |        |
24       44
```

Then, in turn, we balance those two trees. After balancing they will be as follows.

```
02    
 |__
 |  |    31 
01 03     |__
 |  |     |  |
22 04    42 32
 |  |     |  |
23 53    43 33
 |  |     |
24 52    44
```

So the answer will be nodes 02 and 31.

To make implementation effective enough, we need to cash tree depths for every node. This way we don’t need to recalculate all depths after every reparenting – it’s enough to only recalculate depth for the new root and one new branch after every reparenting.
So, here is the implementation.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.children = []


def construct_tree(pairs):
    pairs = [tuple(list(sorted(pair))) for pair in pairs]
    pairs.sort(reverse=True)
    p, c = pairs.pop()
    root = Node(p)
    child = Node(c)
    root.children.append(child)
    nodes_dic = {p: root, c: child}
    while pairs:
        pair = pairs.pop()
        p, c = pair
        if c in nodes_dic:
            p, c = c, p
        if p in nodes_dic:
            parent = nodes_dic[p]
            node = Node(c)
            parent.children.append(node)
            nodes_dic[c] = node
        else:
            pairs.insert(0, pair)
    return root


def get_depth(node, depths):
    if node.val not in depths:
        if not node.children:
            depths[node.val] = 0
        else:
            depths[node.val] = 1 + max([get_depth(child, depths) for child in node.children])
    return depths[node.val]


def reparent_tree(root, new_root, depths):
    children = [child for child in root.children if child != new_root]
    val = root.val
    if val in depths:
        del depths[val]
    if new_root.val in depths:
        del depths[new_root.val]
    root = new_root
    child = Node(val)
    child.children = children
    root.children.append(child)
    return root


def balance_tree(root):
    depths = {}
    if len(root.children) == 0:
        return root, None
    if len(root.children) == 1:
        root = reparent_tree(root, root.children[0], depths)
    if get_depth(root, depths) < 2:
        return root, root.children[0]
    while True:
        ls = [get_depth(node, depths) for node in root.children]
        l1, l2 = list(sorted(ls))[-2:]
        ind = ls.index(l2)
        candidate_root = root.children[ind]
        if l2 - l1 <= 1:
            break
        root = reparent_tree(root, candidate_root, depths)
    return root, candidate_root


def f(pairs):
    if len(pairs) <= 2:
        return pairs[0]
    root = construct_tree(pairs)
    root, tree1 = balance_tree(root)
    root.children.remove(tree1)
    tree2 = root
    tree1, _ = balance_tree(tree1)
    tree2, _ = balance_tree(tree2)
    return tree1.val, tree2.val
```

The solution passes my test cases – both handmade and a number of randomly generated without runtime error and it’s hard to figure out what went wrong.